# How to change the window rect without redrawing it

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I want to change the height of an edit control window at 1st and then visualize the change through calling `AnimateWindow` function. But it doesn't seems to work. What should I do for this?

Comment: `AnimateWindow` will only show/hide the window. To animate window re-sizing you have to re-size little by little, for example through `WM_TIMER`

Answer (score 1):

Use `MoveWindow` with `bRepaint=FALSE`

```
BOOL WINAPI MoveWindow(
  _In_ HWND hWnd,
  _In_ int  X,
  _In_ int  Y,
  _In_ int  nWidth,
  _In_ int  nHeight,
  _In_ BOOL bRepaint // <-- FALSE
);
```

Comment: I tried movewindow with bRepaint FALSE but it still doesn't prevent the window being redrawn.